# How to make a new <tr> if id in the next record is different

Tags: php, mysql, loops, html-table

Let's say I have this result of my query:

```
id_unsur | nama_subunsur
---------+--------------
       1 | subunsur1
       1 | subunsur1
       2 | subunsur3
```

I want to fetch my result into a table, and if `id` is the same as the `id` in the next result I don't want to echo a new `<tr>`, and if it's different then echo new `<tr>`. What I want is:

```
1 | subunsur1
2 | subunsur3
```

I want to do that in:

```
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    // I want to do that here...
}
```

There is no problem in my query, I'm not using group by because the other field result is different. So how to do that? 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You could probably remove the need for this by using a `SELECT DISTINCT` instead of `SELECT` (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html))

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty array outside while loop.

Whenever printing any id push its id in array.

before printing check if that id is present in that array.

Pseudocode

```
if(id present in array){
  dont print
}else {
  print tr
  push it to array
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid Duplicated rows use `DISTINCT` clause in a select statment.

```
SELECT DISTINCT columns FROM table_name WHERE where_conditions;
```